# Rails: Eager loading associated records with an outer join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table that shows all customers and all jobs for each customers. To speed up the page load, I have to eager load the associated jobs as shown below.

However, there are two issues with this approach:

1. `Customers` that don't have a job don't get loaded even though there's no `joins()` method
2. I have to use slow Ruby to sort jobs for each customer by `jobs.id`.

Is there a solution?

```
# http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations
@customers = Customer.all.includes(:jobs).where(jobs: {booking_status: [2,3]}).order('users.id ASC').references(:jobs)

@customers.each do |customer|
  puts customer.full_name
  jobs = customer.jobs.sort_by {|job| job.id}
  jobs.each do |job|
    puts job.id
```

Comment: You're not getting non-job customers due to your where clause. You're stating that you only want customers with a specific booking_status. Try replacing your where clause with something like: `where("jobs.booking_status = ? OR count(jobs) = ?", [2,3], 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a has_many to customer

```
has_many :special_jobs, -> { where(booking_status: [2,3]).order(:id) }, :class_name => 'Job'
```

Then do

```
@customers = Customer.includes(:special_jobs).order(:id)
```

And then in the view refer to customer.special_jobs

```
# this is haml
- @customers.each do |customer|
  %tr
    %td= customer.name
    %td= customer.special_jobs.map { |job| link_to(job.name, job) }.join(', ')
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Small spelling mistake: `Customer.includes` with an s.